# WPF Grid Splitter is not splitting

Tags: c#, wpf

I have listviews which have been ordered up to down. I put grid splitters between each listview. But the grid splitters are not working. I could not find out why they aren't working.

My codes are below.

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ListView Margin="1" Background="Snow" >

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="Attributes" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="55" />
                            <local:ListViewExt Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="300" MinHeight="200"/>
                            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,35"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="Aktivitäten"  Grid.Row="3" Width="50"/>
                            <local:ListViewExt Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Height="300" MinHeight="200"/>
                            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,38"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="Projekte" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Width="50" />
                            <local:ListViewExt Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Height="300" MinHeight="200"/>
                            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,38"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="Akcademy" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Width="55" />
                            <local:ListViewExt Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" Height="300" MinHeight="200"/>
                        </Grid>

                </ListView>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the grid splitter a Vertical Orientation

Comment: @Sisyphe i have edited rowdefinitions height. I edited them to Auto.